# How to compare global variable with class variable and print its value

Tags: python

I have below situation:

```
class data:
    one = "FIRST"
    two = "SECOND"
    three = "THIRD"  
class bandwidth:
    pkgone = "TINY"
    pkgtwo = "MEDIUM"
    pkgthree = "ABOVE MEDIUM"   

analysis = <some slicing from a dict>
```

Lets say:

> print(analysis)
>
> one

Now I want to print value of a class variable which which has variable **one**. So output should be like:

> output = logic here
>
> print(output)
>
> FIRST

How should I achieve this?

Comment: possible dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables

Answer (score 0):

Use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)

```
>>> getattr(data, 'one')
'FIRST'
```

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions. I gave a try in different way and got succeeded.